# Is htmlentities($password_string) necessary?

Tags: php, html

I watched a php login tutorial on a commercial platform where it is advised to use `htmlentities()` on a password string which is given via POST-Method.

As the password is never displayed isn't it wrong to use this function as it alters the password which was entered by the user? I know that this will only affect html codes but is it really non-safe to not use the function as the password is never displayed?

Comment: It depends that  how much you are concerned about security. May be some one can just enter some script in that section and your application is crashed or hacked

Comment: @Julius It makes no sense and is a strong indicator that the author had no idea what they are writing about.

Comment: We'd really need some context (if you want to populate the `<input type="password">` it could be a valid option, not the best one but a valid one).

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález The `$password_string` comes from a html form, I fetch the data via `$_POST['password']`. The data is immediately hashed using `password_hash()` and this hash is stored in the database.

Comment: @zerkms "I ***watched***…" - probably means YouTube, which automatically disqualifies it IMO. :-D

Comment: @zerkms Lol no, it is a commercial platform for tutorials and there is a big programming section. I paid money for this but got suspicious when the author built a php script that makes it easy to change the password of every user without being some kind of admin just by modifying some GET-Parameters in the URL. I told him about this and he was like "This tutorial is just a start and you can modify it to your own needs blabla" I mean, this is a huge security issue and not even telling the users about it is some really strange behaviour.

Comment: I'd ask for a refund.

Comment: Escaping a raw password to be displayed into 7-bit HTML code right before hashing it is an effective way to corrupt it. As soon as one of your users chooses a good password he will be locked out of the site without any explanation unless you manage to corrupt the password in the same way every time he signs in. That tutorial is pure junk.

Comment: So to sum up - I can just take the raw password via POST-Method, put it into the `hash_password()` function and store it?

Comment: Yes, exactly right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The one and only time you use `htmlentities` for anything is if and when you're outputting data into HTML, right then and there. E.g.:

```
<p><?php echo htmlentities($data); ?></p>
```

In any other context HTML entities are generally useless* and will only garble/change/destroy your data. Indeed, using it on a password, probably nowhere near any HTML context, is highly suspect.

<sub>* Yes, you can probably find some specialised use case somewhere…</sub>

Comment: Also see [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Comment: Additionally, printing a clear password has less valid usages than one might think.